# Spring Security UI moves everything left top

Tags: css, grails, spring-security

I am using Spring security UI and every time I add

```
<r:require module="register"/>
<r:layoutResources/>
```

(this should add the style for spring security UI)

To my head of the auth file it moves my page from being nicely centered to top left

any Ideas?

I know its something to do with the reset.css file but each time i change it it also changes the login fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this way of centering a page but in the reset.css file in the plugin add this code to the bottom.

```
html {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1024px;
}
```